# How factory reset a android smartphone without using the volume up button

Tags: factory-reset

How can I factory reset my android phone without using the volume up button? The phone is a zte android. Seems like recovery mode is missing.

Comment: Please specify the phone model for easier help. But as a general concept

Answer (score -1):

Please specify the phone model for easier help. But as a general concept, phones have recovery mode, factory mode and fastboot mode. All these can be used to reset, with just a few presses or a few commands, and also note entering into recovery mode needs a unique button combination as per the device model you're using. Kindly search a specific key combo for your phone and it could be easier because practically there's no android without recovery mode unless explicitly deleted during an amateur or professionally intended software flash